# I'd like to mix these two sentences using 'more than' and 'as .. as ~' sentence patter

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

I'm comfortable saying like this:

> 1. My ex was a vegetarian and that's why I got a lot of chance to eat vegetables.
> 2. If my ex hadn't been a vegetarian I wouldn't have gotten a lot of chance to eat vegetables.

And I'd like to mix these two.

> 3. My ex was a vegetarian and that's why I got ***more*** chance to eat vegetables ***than*** I would have if my ex hadn't been a vegetarian.
> 4. If my ex hadn't been a vegetarian I wouldn't have gotten ***as much chance to eat vegetables as*** I actually got .

Can I say like #3 and #4 using ***more than*** and ***as ~ as..*** sentence pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could. But first, I would fix your usage of  "chance".  You get "a lot of (or more) **chances**", not "a lot of (or more) **chance**".  And you can have "as many **chances**" or "as much *of a***chance**".  Whether "chance" is a count noun depends on whether you think of *a chance* as a discrete  opportunity, or of *chance* as a continuously variable level of likelihood.

Anyway, number 4 sounds okay, except that I would say **as many chances**" rather than "as much chance"

Number 3, however, seems long-winded.  I would simplify it thus:

- My ex was a vegetarian, and that's why I got more chances to eat vegetables than I would have **otherwise.**